# I have to grep over the same file several thousand times. Is there a way to optimize the process?

Tags: bash, shell, search, awk, grep

I have a script that looks through the same file over and over again for different identifiers. The file itself (`input.vcf`) is a tab-delimited text file.

Basically, I need to match a line that has the needed value (`$POS`) as its second entry, and return the 4th entry (there are 20 entries in each row). The command itself looks like this right now:

`LC_ALL=C cat input.vcf | fgrep -w -m 1 $POS | awk '{ FS=OFS="\t"; print $4 }'`

I'm using `LC_ALL=C, -m 1, fgrep` to speed things up, but it's still painfully slow, and definitely not optimal: during each iteration, I'm skimming over the lines that I will have to look for later again!

Essentially I'm asking two questions: **[1]** maybe there's a better way to solve this particular task (using something else instead of grep)? **[2]** regardless of this concrete task, are there ways to make grep faster when I have to access the same file over and over again? *(searching for "grep index" etc didn't yield anything meaningful for me)*.

Comment: GNU `grep` has `--mmap` which could be worth trying.

Comment: That's a useless use of cat. Just give grep the file directly (for which, as indicated, `--mmap` might speed things up some).

Comment: Do you need the matching lines spit out by whatever `$POS` is in order of how you loop over `$POS`? Or can you spit out the fourth entry for a line that matches any `$POS` in file order?

Comment: This cat isn't needed, LANG=C fgrep -w … is enough.

Comment: You might want to import the text file into a proper database and query that, instead of running `grep` repeatedly.

Comment: I don't see a loop in your code. Is there some surrounding loop you're not telling us about that's changing the value of POS? If so, show us so we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `cat and grep` you can do all that in awk itself:

```
LC_ALL=C awk -v P="$POS" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} index($0, P){ print $4 }' input.vcf
```

Comment: That's not quite the same since awk is going to treat P as a regex and not a fixed string. Though it might work nonethless.

Comment: `grep -m 1` outputs only the first occurrence of the string, so a `quit` statement would speed things further up?

Comment: Why are you assigning to FS in the action?

Comment: @EtanReisner: Sorry that was bad syntax. Fixed it now. Thanks!

Comment: @pfnuesel: `exit` can be called after `print $4` if that is needed.

Comment: The OP said he just wanted to test for the $POS being in $2, not across the whole line.

Comment: He did but his code didn't. Though that's probably just an artifact of using grep.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `-f` option to grep, you can scan for all the strings at once, which is probably faster. For example, you could use something like this, assuming that all the strings you care about are in the file `matches`, one per line:

```
grep -F -f matches input.vcf | cut -f2,4 | sort
```

The `cut` extracts the second and fourth field. I pass it to `sort` so that the output will be sorted by the (original) second field; it's slightly more complicated if you need them sorted in the original order.

That's imprecise, though, because `grep` will match the target strings anywhere, and I believe you are attempting to match the second field precisely. You could put leading and trailing tab characters in each line of `matches`, but it will still match the target in any column, not just the second one. For more precision, it's better to use `awk`.

The following awk program first builds a hash-table from the strings (as before, placed one per line in `matches`), and then reads the target file once, testing the second column of each line. It then rereads the target strings, in order to print the results out in the correct order:

```
awk -V MATCH_FILE=matches \
     'BEGIN  { while (getline <MATCH_FILE) m[$0]=""; close(MATCH_FILE); }
     $2 in m { m[$2] = $4 }
     END     { while (getline <MATCH_FILE) if (m[$0]) printf "%s\t%s\n", $0, m[$0]; }
     ' input.vcf
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you have multiple values of POS you're interested in and that's why you mention iterations. Get rid of the loop (if any) and try this:

```
POSes="1 2 3"
awk -F'\t' -v POSes="$POSes" '
   BEGIN{ split(POSes,tmp); for (i in tmp) poses[tmp[i]] }
   $2 in poses{ print $4 }
' input.vcf
```

Obviously populate the shell variable POSes with whatever set of values you're interested in or just 1 value if that's what you want but then the script should really be reduced to:

```
POS="1"
awk -F'\t' -v pos="$POS" '$2 == pos{ print $4 }' input.vcf
```

Add `; exit` after `print $4` in the latter case for efficiency if necessary and there's only 1 possible match.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you have a very large tab-delimited file.  You want to select on column 2 and report the value of column 4.  The problem is that you have thousands of column 2 values of interest and it is slow to go through the file thousands of times.

As a speed up, you might consider reducing the number of times that you go through your large file, picking out many column 2 values of interest in one pass.  For example, if you data was in the file if you were interested in selecting column 2 values which match either $pos1 or $pos2, you could try:

```
LC_ALL=C awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} ( $2=="'$pos1'" || $2=="'$pos2'" ) {print $2,$4}' input.vcf
```

Of course, don't limit it to just two at once.  The shell script below takes arbitrarily many column-2 values as arguments and only needs to scan your large file once:

```
#!/bin/sh
condition=" \$2==\"$1\" "
shift

for pos in "$@"
do
    condition="$condition || \$2==\"$pos\""
done

LC_ALL=C awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} ( '"$condition"' ) {print $2,$4}' input.vcf
```

As I read your question, it sounded like an equality test for column 2 would be satisfactory (and likely *much faster* than a regular expression).  If you need regex, the script and awk command is easily changed.

Answer (score 0):

`1`. Yes, there are many ways of making this faster. Exactly how depends on the rest of your program.

Why are you searching the file over and over?

Because entries keep being added? Use `tail -f` to not re-read data.

Because you have a long list of IDs to look up? Use grep with multiple patterns, and do a single pass.

Because you have some serial logic that depends on the previous lookup, like trying to find the original ancestor from a "child,parent" list? Use awk, stick the data in an associative array and query it in constant time.

`2`. No, there are no good ways of optimizing using grep repeatedly over an entire file.

This is like asking "How do I unroll and hand optimize a tight, inner loop? My bubble sort is slow".